# Displaying the plots stored in a list, suppressing the names and indices from printing into console

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a few `ggplot2` plots stored in a named list, `plt_list`,  and I would like to display the plots in R or Rmarkdown, without the names or list indices (e.g. `[[1]]`) to be displayed; just the plots. I have tried `unname(plt_list)`, but the indices are printed into the console (or in Rmarkdown document, before each plot). With `invisible` nothing is displayed. Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to display them at once without indexing into the list: akin to running `plt_list` in the console and see all the plots shown at once.  I tried to read the list elements in a for loop using `[[` but not successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `walk` from `purrr` to display in Rmarkdown

````
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


```{r plot_create, echo = FALSE}

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr))
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_col()
plt_lst <- list(p1 = p1, p2 = p1, p3 = p1)
```

```{r plots, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
walk(plt_lst, print)
```
````

-output

[image]

---

If we are trying this in R console, a `for` loop should also work

```
for(i in seq_along(plt_lst)) plt_lst[[i]]
```